# Calculate weight of courses

Tags: microsoft-excel, mathematica

I'm trying to calculate the total value of three courses that have the weights 30%, 35%, 35%. It can be that a student didn't have to do a class which means that his cell would be empty and the weight of the two other courses would increase with the weight of the course (empty cell) divided by two. My cells are:

- A - Student Names
- B - points Course1
- C - points Course2
- D - points Course3

When entering this code I get an error. Could someone please help me

```
=IF(COUNTA(B2:D2) = 3, SUMPRODUCT(B2:D2, {0.30, 0.35, 0.35}),
 IF(ISBLANK(B2), SUM(B2 * 0.475, D2 * 0.525),
 IF(ISBLANK(C2), SUM(B2 * 0.475, D2 * 0.525),
 IF(ISBLANK(D2), SUM(B2 * 0.475, C2 * 0.525), ""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake when calculating the weights when a course is empty. It should be

- When B is empty: C * 0.5 + D * 0.5
- When C is empty: B * 0.475 + D * 0.525
- When D is empty: B * 0.475 + C * 0.525

Your formula must be changed to:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B2:D2) = 3, SUMPRODUCT(B2:D2, {0.3,0.35,0.35}),
 IF(ISBLANK(B2), SUM(C2 * 0.5, D2 * 0.5),
 IF(ISBLANK(C2), SUM(B2 * 0.475, D2 * 0.525),
 IF(ISBLANK(D2), SUM(B2 * 0.475, C2 * 0.525), ""))))
```

[image]

**Demo**

[image]